# UIHostingController intrinsicContentSize is incorrect on initialize even with the simplest possible view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have been scratching my head over this for some time. I noticed my layouts being slightly off when adding `UIHostingController` views to a view controller. Consider the simplest possible example:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SquareView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(.orange)
            .frame(width: 50.0, height: 50.0)
    }
}

struct SquareView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SquareView()
    }
}
```

And now in a view controller:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let squareView = SquareView()
        let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: squareView)
        addChild(hostingController)
        hostingController.didMove(toParent: self)

        view.addSubview(hostingController.view)
        hostingController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let leading = hostingController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant:32.0)
        let top = hostingController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 32.0)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([leading, top])

        // Wait some time for the layout
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
            // Now the size is correct!
            hostingController.view.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
    }

}
```

When initially added to the view the intrinsic content size will be incorrect (the blue border is the intrinsic size):

[image]

This was causing my view to appear to have a bigger inset than `32.0` when pinned to the top.

If I wait for the layout and call `hostingController.view.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()` the size will update correctly:

[image]

Now I know I can use `DispatchQueue.main.async` instead of a delay, and that will work on this layout. But in some situations using `DispatchQueue.main.async` doesn't work since the layout still isn't ready. Note that calling `hostingController.view.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is also not a solution since it will create an infinite loop.

It seems like complete madness that this doesn't work out of the box. Am I missing something here? How can I set the `intrinsicContentSize` correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding delays to wait for the layout to happen, how about just asking it to happen immediately by calling `layoutIfNeeded`?

```
// do this after activating constraints
view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Note that it is called on `view`, rather than `hostingController.view`. This is important, because the square does not need any lay anything out - it is `self.view` that needs to lay out the square.

Also, since the `ViewController` is now in charge of positioning positioning the view away from the safe area, you should make the SwiftUI view ignore safe area:

```
let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: squareView.ignoresSafeArea())
```

Without this, SwiftUI is going to add a non-zero safe area insets to `hostingController.view`, thinking that there is a safe area that it has to avoid.

Comment: My mistake I didn't add `hostingController.didMove(toParent: self)`. I fixed the question. With `hostingController.didMove(toParent: self)` and calling `hostingController.view.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()` immediately the problem persists.

However I noticed you call `view.layoutIfNeeded()`. Calling `view.layoutIfNeeded()` immediately works and `hostingController.view.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()` isn't needed

Comment: Reopening this. This solution worked on iPhone 8 iOS 15.5 but not on iPhone13 15.5, any ideas what that would be?

Comment: @Kex That appears to be a different problem about safe areas. Check out `hostingController.view.safeAreaInsets`. Also see the edit.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this issue happened intermittently in some cases, for example after dismissing a modal view on top of the `UIHostingController`.

The only way I could find to fix this was to wrap my SwiftUI view in a `GeometryReader`. Setting a fixed frame height in the swiftui view didn't work either.

In my case the UIHostigController has an fixed height constraint. HOpe it helps.